# Google Maps API to determine routes based on distance

Tags: react-native, google-maps, react-native-maps

As a runner, I have not quite been able to find an app that meets my needs so I figured I should just make it. However, as a developer I'm new to Google Maps API, and would love some direction as to how best to proceed.

Basically I want to specify a distance in miles, and discover several routes from my current location. The routes need to be round trips--since I want to run out, and then return home.

So if I set 5 miles, then I want to find points that are 2.5 miles away from my location, and generate the routes as options to run.

I currently am using React Native, React-native-maps to find my location and render the map, I just don't have any idea how to start determining routes based on points that are x distance away from me.

Everything that I have found so far dals with getting routes to specific locations, but I would to find routes based on distance from starting point.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You could draw a 5 mile diameter circle around your current location and let the user select a point near the circle. Of course this wouldn't be exactly a 5 mile route, but it would get you in the ballpark. If Google doesn't offer an API that does this for you, the alternative is pretty request- and logic-heavy.

Comment: I was thinking of doing something similar. Is there a way that I can detect a point on a road X distance away? I feel like if I could figure that out, I could probably handle the rest

Comment: Have you tried using the [geolib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geolib#:~:text=computeDestinationPoint(point%2C%20distance%2C%20bearing%2C%20radius%20%3D%20earthRadius)) library?

You can check the computeDestinationPoint where you input your current coords, distance, bearing and radius to return a destination coordinate however note that this is not only for roads but on the radius of your location.

Comment: Looks promising, will investigate